Speed up column insertion
In Windows 11 / Office 2021, I want to insert information in column A 51 times, skipping column D, column F, column H, and column CZ.
This runs slowly.
Sub 列挿入()

Dim stepNo As Integer
Dim copyStart As Integer
Dim copyEnd As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer

stepNo = 3    '入力：１つの列幅
copyStart = 1 '入力：コピーする列の最初の列No
copyEnd = 1    '入力：コピーする列の最後の列No
y = 52 '入力：繰り返す数

For i = stepNo + 1 To stepNo * y Step stepNo
    Range (Columns(copyStart), Columns(copyEnd)). Copy
    Columns(i). Insert xlShiftToRight
Next i

End Sub

I tried this, but it didn't change.

Boot in safe mode
Uncheck "Enable real-time preview display function"
Uncheck "LinkedIN function"


Try the Code Review Stack, as the code works - we tend to look at code that does not work here.

Try using Application.ScreenUpdating = False before your loop. Set it to True after the loop

...and set Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual. Set it to xlCalculationAutomatic after you're done

There a few ways to optimize your code, try the ideas bellow.

turn off the automatic calculations and the screen update, u may do this by the line bellow.


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Apply this method on the begin of your code and the end for reactivate.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


Try to use a diferrent range method, instead of copy the entire column, use a range method to limit to just the number of lines in use. something like implementing the lines bellow.

usedRangeRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Find the last used row in column A

    Columns(insertAt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(usedRangeRow, 1)).Copy Destination:=Cells(1, insertAt)

This option will improve your code.

Arrays can be your friend here - especially if the number of elements (cells in column A) is not relatively huge. Precisely, less than 32768 values. You can populate an array of Variant type (it stores elements regardless of their type) with values from column A and then insert copied values to the corresponding range in next columns. Code:
Sub SO_post_macro()
  
  'optimization tip - you can see the effect after code execution and you won't get any alerts (if applicable)
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With
  
  'optimization tip - works only when a workbook is on an Onedrive/Sharepoint account
  On Error Resume Next
  ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim stepNo As Integer
  Dim copyStart As Integer
  Dim copyEnd As Integer

  Dim y As Integer
  Dim i As Integer

  stepNo = 3
  copyStart = 1
  copyEnd = 1
  
  y = 52
  
  'determining last used row (last row with non-empty value)
  Dim lngLastUsedRow As Long
  lngLastUsedRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  
  'populating an array
  Dim arrValuesToCopy() As Variant
  arrValuesToCopy() = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lngLastUsedRow, 1)).Value
  
  'length of the array
  Dim lngArrLen As Long
  lngArrLen = UBound(arrValuesToCopy()) - LBound(arrValuesToCopy()) + 1
  
  For i = stepNo + 1 To stepNo * y Step stepNo
    
    Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lngArrLen, i)).Value = arrValuesToCopy()
  
  Next i
  
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
  End With
  
  'optimization tip - erasing array when not used anymore
  Erase arrValuesToCopy()
  
  On Error Resume Next
  ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = True
  On Error GoTo 0
  
  'optional message box
  MsgBox "FINISHED"

End Sub

Important: VBA has to store empty values too so this solution works best when ranges of non-empty cells are close to each other. What I found interesting is that even though you don't have to specify last row in the subsequent columns to insert array values (Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lngArrLen, i))) - it improves performance when you do.
EDIT: obviously, arrays in VBA can be longer than 32767. See comments below. However, make sure you correctly determine range where to take values from. That's why you should add 1 to lngLastUsedRow.

There's no 32k limit on arrays

@TimWilliams - I purposefully inserted a value in 1048576th row and only first 32767 elements were read and inserted :(

This for example shows 100k is no problem -  [A1:A100000].Formula = "=ROW()":  [B1:B100000].Value = [A1:A100000].Value:Debug.Print [B100000].Value prints 100000

@SorenV.Raben if your code truncate at 32767, that suggests you're using an Integer variable somewhere where you should be using Long

@chrisneilsen - I converted all the variables to long. Value in the last row was still present. I checked lngLastUsedRow and it was smaller than 1048576. However, when i entered a value in A1048575 the result was 1048575. Strange... It looks like the last row is not read for some reason.

Cells(Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row if you try putting a value in the last cell of a column, then selecting that cell and pressing Ctrl+Up, the selection will always move up...

You can perform the insert/copy in batched mode:
Sub Tester()
    Const INSERT_START_COL As Long = 3
    Const NUM_INSERTS As Long = 51
    Const INSERT_STEP As Long = 2
    Const COPY_COL As Long = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, c As Range, i As Long, n As Long, t
    
    t = Timer
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    
    i = INSERT_START_COL     'first insert position
    Set rng = ws.Cells(1, i)
    For n = 1 To NUM_INSERTS - 1
        i = i + INSERT_STEP
        Set rng = Application.Union(rng, ws.Cells(1, i))
    Next n
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rng.EntireColumn.Insert                'insert all columns
    ws.Columns(COPY_COL).Copy rng.Offset(0, -1)   'copy content over
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t

End Sub

